# Jest mock is not properly used/replaced in Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I have one simple Ionic/Angular component. I reduced other unnecessary code.

```
import { IonicModule, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputParam: Organization;

  public paramOne: string;

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramOne = this.inputParam?.id;
  }

  onClickClose(): void {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

My test is also extremely simple. I am using jest:

```
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let ionicModalControllerMock = {
     dismiss: jest.fn()
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MyComponent, NoopAnimationsModule],
      providers: [{ provide: ModalController, useValue: ionicModalControllerMock }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

   it('should dismiss the modal without data on close click', () => {
     component.onClickClose();
     expect(ionicModalControllerMock.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
   });
});
```

My problem is that my **ionicModalControllerMock** is not being used correctly. My test fails with the error that the **dismiss** method was never called. In the debugger I see that my mock is not being used. And in many other places/tests this kind of mock works for me. Is there something I missed here?